# Why do I get the sign "?" at the start of the URL and reboot the app when navigating the absolute path?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem.

I have a multi-module application with lazy loading.
When I navigate from top module to bottom child module, everything is fine.
But when I try to route from a bottom child lazy module to another child lazy module, I get strange behavior.

It's ok :

```
=> http://localhost:4200/#/op/services/ =>
=> http://localhost:4200/#/op/services/management/ =>
=> http://localhost:4200/#/op/services/management/edit/123

=> http://localhost:4200/#/op
=> http://localhost:4200/#/op/test/management/
=> http://localhost:4200/#/op/test/management/edit/321
```

This is bad:

```
http://localhost:4200/#/op/test/management/edit/321 =>
=> http://localhost:4200/#/op/services/management/edit/123
```

When I try it, I got '?' sign in start URL, like

`http://localhost:4200/?#/op/services/management/edit/123`

and my app was full reload!

It doesn't matter if a lazy module is loaded or not, as I found out, this does not affect the problem.

This problem is repeated unstable, sometimes the transition works as expected!
I tried many combinations, but the problem can not solve.

That I tried:

```
this.router.navigate([op/services/management/edit/${id}]);
this.router.navigate([/op/services/management/edit/${id}]);
this.router.navigate(['/op/services/management/edit/', id]);

this.router.navigateByUrl(op/services/management/edit/${id});
this.router.navigateByUrl(/op/services/management/edit/${id});

routerLink = "/op/services/management/edit/123"
routerLink = "op/services/management/edit/123"
```

Help me understand why the route changes?

UPDATE.

Add smiplify route config:

Basic module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', loadChildren: './path/to/op.module#OperatorModule',
    data: {
      preload: false,
      base: true,
    },
  },
  ...
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(
    routes,
    {
      useHash: true,
      preloadingStrategy: SelectivePreloadingStrategy,
    },
  )],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Operator module which contains my inner lazy modules:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'op',
    component: BasePage,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        {
            path: 'services/management',
            loadChildren: './services/services.module#ServicesModule',
            canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            data: {
              preload: true,
            },
        },
        {
            path: 'tests/management',
            loadChildren: './tests/tests.module#TestsModule',
            canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            data: {
              preload: true,
            },
        },
      ...
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class OperatorRoutingModule {
}
```

Router modules for some of inner module:

For services:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
        ...
    },
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: ServicesPage,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'edit/:id',
    data: {
      accessRole: [UserRole.USER, UserRole.ADMIN],
    },
    component: ServicePage,
    canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, RoleGuard],
  },
  ....
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ServicesRoutingModule {
}
```

For tests:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
        ...
    },
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: TestsPage,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'edit/:id',
    data: {
      accessRole: [UserRole.USER, UserRole.ADMIN],
    },
    component: TestPage,
    canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, RoleGuard],
  },
  ....
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TestsRoutingModule {
}
```

UPDATE!

I found a new reason.
The problem happens if I try to make the routing in HTML form.
I have a CanDeactivate service warning about leaving the page.
I noticed that the `window:befeoreonload` works on any form, even if disabled CanDeactivate service on this page.

I have not yet understood, how it can be dependent, but I think, I'm on the right way.

Comment: Try like this. this._router.navigate(['/op/services/management/edit/', id]);

Comment: What is '_router' ?
I also try something like this: 
this.router.navigate(['/op/services/management/edit/', id]);

Comment: Share your routing configuration.

Comment: The issue is, way of Forming the router URL has issues.

Comment: see my updates, please

Comment: I also try refactor this, and union all Operator components to one module but it's not help me..

Answer (score 0):

The route button had a default type, that is, 'submit', and its button was in form...
Change it to type='button' and all work fine!